# Insertar datos/filas/registros desde la migración en Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy creando una migración en laravel 5.8 y la tabla que estoy creando tiene ya unos valores predefinidos que no van a cambiar a lo largo del programa.

Se puede realizar un insert desde la migración, o solamente se puede insertar después de la migración

Comment: La migración es para crear la estructura de la tabla o para agregar o quitar columnas a dichas tablas, por favor se mas claro en tu duda

Comment: Voy a crear la tabla 'ciudades' donde solo voy a registrar 5 ciudades que necesito.  Al crear la tabla, puedo insertar los 5 registros en el mismo archivo de migración, o ejecuto la migración y luego desde el gestor de bases de datos ingreso los datos

Comment: Entonces bien puedes crear la migración y después poblar tu tabla a través de un Seeder

Answer (score 1):

Las migraciones funcionan para:

- crear la estructura de tus tablas
- agregar columnas a una tabla ya existente
- eliminar columnas a una tabla ya existente
- ... etc

Por lo tanto tu debes proceder pero de este modo:

Apóyate del sistema de `Seeders` que te permitirán insertar registros en tu tabla **Ciudades**

Comienza por teclar el siguiente comando desde la consola a nivel de la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto:

```
php artisan make:seeder CiudadesTableSeeder
```

Ahora dentro de tu **proyecto/database/seeders** tendrás un nuevo archivo con extensión `.php` y con el nombre que indicaste en el comando anterior.

Tu siguiente paso deberá ser componer la estructura interna en el método `run()` para hacer la inserción múltple de valores así:

Que debería lucir así:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CiudadesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        return \DB::table('ciudades')->insert([
            [
                "columna1" => $valor1,
                "columna2" => $valor2
            ],
            [
                "columna1" => $valor1,
                "columna2" => $valor2
            ],
                        [
                "columna1" => $valor1,
                "columna2" => $valor2
            ],
                        [
                "columna1" => $valor1,
                "columna2" => $valor2
            ],
                        [
                "columna1" => $valor1,
                "columna2" => $valor2
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Lo único relevante es que:

Al tratarse de un array asociativo:

- La clave es el nombre de la columna en tu tabla
- El valor es el *valor* que le asignarás a dicha columna

Lo siguiente que debes realizar es abrir el archivo llamado: **DatabaseSeeder.php** el cual deberá *recibir el llamado* en el método `run()` de la clase `CiudadesTableSeeder` de esta forma:

Tu código debería lucir así:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(CiudadesTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Finalmente ejecutas el siguiente comando para proceder con el `seeding` de los datos

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Todo lo anterior deberá insertar los 5 registros nuevos sin comprometer los que ya se encuentran existentes.

**Referencias**

- [Seeds Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/seeding)